# Get XDEBUG_SESSION_START header in Phalcon request

Tags: php, apache, microservices, xdebug, phalcon

I am trying to remotely start debugger in multiple microservices using Phalcon, the first microservice accepts `XDEBUG_SESSION_START` header but I cannot get the header in the request when I instantiate the Request object so I guess that Apache is removing it after the debugger starts.

Is it exists any option or way to disable this behavior and make the Phalcon code know when the Xdebug flag is present in the Request in order to forward that flag when calling other microservices?

I know that I can set `auto_start` option for Xdebug but that option seems to slow down the microservices.

The final code should looks similar to:

```
$DEBUG = $request.getHeaders()['XDEBUG_SESSION_START']

if (!is_empty($DEBUG)) {
    $headers['XDEBUG_SESSION_START'] == 1;
} 

....
```

I think this would be OK and it will not cause problems even when code will be deployed to PROD environments.

Comment: 1) `XDEBUG_SESSION_START` is not a HTTP header but an ordinary GET/POST parameter. 2) You better look at Xdebug cookie (browser extensions for Xdebug do just that -- they set cookie instead of possibly modifying URLs; this allows it to transparently work with Ajax and POST requests (same domain:port)). See more at https://xdebug.org/docs/remote

Comment: My API does not support cookies

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "My API does not support cookies"? Are you (or Phalcon) forcibly removing them from `$request`? Or you have some gateway (load balancer/whataver etc) in front that does that? In any case: if you cannot use cookies then you need to look at GET/POST parameter as that's what Xdebug uses.. unless you are using custom request header here and processing it later in your code (programmatically invoking Xdebug during runtime).

Comment: The app is running in docker, how should I proceed to try this? I am new with xdebug am I am a bit lost.

Comment: It does not matter where it is running -- Xdebug's "debug me" flag is part of the HTTP request (regardless if it's a cookie, param or your custom header). Therefore cookie should work just fine, link to Xdebug docs on how it all works is in my first comment. Configuring Xdebug to connect to your IDE/editor (VSCode, PhpStorm etc) will have some nuances (as Xdebug needs to connecet from inside the container to the IDE, not other way around) but that is not the question/subject here.